# Take only one value from variadic

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to ask through this simple example: how could I take the last value from a variadic pack and `print(1, 2, 3.14)` to call `print(3,14)`?

```
void print()
{
   cout<<"--empty--";
}

void print(x)
{
    std::cout<<"Last Value from variadic pac--" << x;
}
      
template <typename T, typename... Types>
void print(T var1, Types... var2)
{ 
   int x = // last value from variadic pac : 3.14
   print(x) // 3.14 
}
  
int main()
{
    print(1, 2, 3.14);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `std::tuple`, you might do

```
template <typename T, typename... Types>
void print(T var1, Types... var2)
{ 
   auto x = std::get<sizeof...(Types) - 1>(std::tie(var2...));
   print(x); // 3.14 
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/096c35c8b44bf377)

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42, changed to template <typename T, typename... Types>
void print(T var1, Types... var2)
{ 
  auto x = std::get<sizeof(Types ...) - 1>(std::tie(var2));
  print(x) // 3.14 
}
and I got  error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:

Comment: Maybe you can remove the `typename T`/`T var1` part (just in case the function is called only with an argument). Or you can maintain `var1` but adding it in the tuple.

Comment: @DanFlick: typo fixed, and link demo added.

Comment: @max66: OP provides overload for 0/1 argument just above, so not required.

Comment: what should I change auto x = std::get<sizeof...(Types) - 1>(std::tie(var2...)) to in order to get the first element from pac ?

Comment: Isn't the explicit recursion useless, though, given that `std::get` already [gives the last element](https://godbolt.org/z/dcW5Kv6qs)?

Comment: @DanFlick: `std::get<0>` would give first element of the pack (0-indexing).

Comment: yes, I've just seen, the realy first element how I could get ?

Comment: @Bob__: OP state C++11/C++14, so no `if constexpr`. and yes, from current code, some overloads (1, and 2+) can be regrouped.

Comment: @DanFlick: in `print(1, 2, 3.14);`, `1` is in `var1`, and `[2, 3.14]` is in `var2`, `std::get<0>` -> `2`, `std::get<1>` -> `3.14`.

Comment: @DanFlick: If you want to do job for all elements of a pack, there are already Q/A about that on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Though you tagged your question up to c++14, I thought it worth noting that a c++17 solution is much simpler using a fold expression and constexpr if:

In its entirety:

```
template <typename... Types>
void print(Types... args)
{ 
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Types) == 0)
        std::cout << "Empty";
    else
        std::cout << (args, ...);
}
```

The fold expands to using the comma operator, which evaluates each argument and discards the result until the last one is reached.  The last item's evaluation becomes the value of the entire expression, which is printed.

Comment: Thanks, but I need c++14 solution.